# How to check if a sheet name / string contains both letters and numbers in Google Apps Script - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a App Scripts code for checking the sheet names. There two types of sheet names in my project - (i) only alphabets (e.g. master) and (ii) alphabets and numbers together (PHY4125). The code will check the 2nd option. My IF condition often does not work! Is there any other way to do the same task?

My codes:

```
    function autoConvert(e) {    
        var ss=e.source;
        var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
        var key=sh.getName();
        var lastRow=sh.getLastRow();
              
        **if (key.indexOf("0")>-1 || key.indexOf("1")>-1 || key.indexOf("2")>-1 || key.indexOf("3")>-1 || key.indexOf("4")>-1 
          || key.indexOf("5")>-1 || key.indexOf("6")>-1 || key.indexOf("7")>-1 || key.indexOf("8")>-1 || key.indexOf("9")>-1){** 

        //Body of the code block

       }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation:

The regular expression:

`/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]+$/`

will check if the string `key` contains **both** letters **and** digit numbers.

Therefore this expression:

`if(key.match(/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]+$/))`

will evaluate to `true` for cases like `AB23423`, `ab23423`, `23233ab` or `24443AB` or any combination `As23Abc`.

---

### Solution:

```
 function autoConvert(e) {    
        var ss=e.source;
        var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
        var key=sh.getName();
        var lastRow=sh.getLastRow();

       if(key.match(/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]+$/)){
  
    //Body of the code block
  
  }
     
  }
```

Comment: the subject code may be phy4125. It may take capital or small letters. So please revise regular expression. The only difference in sheets name in my project is, one type contains only alphabets and the other type contains alphabets plus numbers. In both cases alphabets may be capital or small

Comment: could you please check my recent post at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64549880/how-to-insert-the-email-address-by-querying-corresponding-id-using-google-app-sc